# In python Compare two array string values and add the value in the array if not

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, compare

I want to compare 2 arrays (column 0 of **data_names** and **species**) and add the value if it is not in **species**. ***data_size*** is the lenght of ***data_names***.

```
species = np.array([])
for i in range(data_size):
    if not data_names[i,0] in species :
        np.insert(species, str, data_names[i,0])
```

I tried many way but I've always an error as

> '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

Can you help me I don't see how to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```py
# create simple list
species = []

# iterate
for i in range(data_size):
   # check name not in list
   if data_names[i,0] not in species:
       # add name to list
       species.append(data_names[i,0])

# convert to numpy array
output = np.array(species)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `insert` method can be an int, slice or sequence of ints. It represents the index at which you want to insert your element(s). You are passing the `str` keyword, which in python refers to the string type. So the interpreter complains about it.
Moreover, the `insert` method returns a new array with your added element but in your snippet your not assigning this new element to a variable, so the result would not have effect.
If you want to prepend the element at the first position you can do:

```
for i in range(data_size):
    if not data_names[i,0] in species :
        species=np.insert(species, 0, data_names[i,0])
```

ref: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html